# How to integrate GMap.NET in WPF? How to work with GMap.NET winforms controls in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, gmap.net

I can not understand how to integrate GMap.NET in WPF. I am trying to do it using XAML and have no ideas. I am trying smth like that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875(v=vs.110).aspx. But it doesn't work for me. So, how to do it?

I have WPF application and want to use GMap.NET lib winforms controls inside WPF window. Smth like that but in WPF:

[image]

Also, in general, how to work with WinForms controls parameters in WPF? How to change Map Provider, for example? In winforms its quite simple, but how to do it in WPF? I got stucked, so. Sample for changing mapprovider:

```
gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.ArcGIS_World_Street_MapProvider.Instance;
```

Or, maybe, I am just on the wrong way? I am completely new in WPF.

Comment: In winforms there is a control that can be used to host wpf controls inside, I'll bet there is it's oppisite in WPF - a control that can host winforms control inside.

Comment: Yep, I know. But I can not understand how to properly use it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to WPF myself, never tried to host a winforms control inside a wpf window...

Comment: There is a [`GMapControl`](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMapControl.cs) for WPF in namespace `GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation`. It has a `MapProvider` property.

Comment: @ValerikPunk, you should use a WPF control for that. It is also available. You can add a WinForms controls, but do not do that, since you have a WPF control.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. add the GMap NET reference to your project so you have "GMap.NET.Core" and "GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation" in your reference list
2. In your XAML file, with the other namespace (xmlns) declarations, add,

   ```
   xmlns:gmaps="clr-namespace:GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation;assembly=GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation"
   ```
3. Add the GMap NET object in to the XAML body where you want it to go, e.g.

```
    <Grid>
    <gmaps:GMapControl x:Name="mapView" Loaded="mapView_Loaded" />
    </Grid>
```

4. In the mapView_Loaded function of the code , set up the map object

```
        private void mapView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
            // choose your provider here
            mapView.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance;
            mapView.MinZoom = 2;
            mapView.MaxZoom = 17;
            // whole world zoom
            mapView.Zoom = 2;
            // lets the map use the mousewheel to zoom
            mapView.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionAndCenter;
            // lets the user drag the map
            mapView.CanDragMap = true;
            // lets the user drag the map with the left mouse button
            mapView.DragButton = MouseButton.Left;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any replacement for gmap.DisableFocusOnMouseCenter for WPF?

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever used it. What does it do?