# Error when Add GMap Control to the Toolbox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, gmap.net

I'm Trying to Add GMap Control in my WPF project. But Got Error Message ("There is no component in GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.dll that can be placed on the toolbox").

[image]

Comment: Please check image link or you can attach image within your question.

Comment: I suggest you try the process described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973526/how-to-integrate-gmap-net-in-wpf-how-to-work-with-gmap-net-winforms-controls-in

Comment: @Andy I'm trying this with getting the error "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'. this specified module could not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Comment: You should have installed the NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GMap.NET.Windows/

Comment: @Clemens I have installed the Package.